# TCP first connection slow

Tags: networking, windows-7, tcp

Consider this TCP communication via ncat on localhost on a Windows 7 machine:

#### Terminal A

```
>ncat -4kvvl 127.0.0.1 5001
Ncat: Version 7.12 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on 127.0.0.1:5001
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1.
Ncat: Connection from 127.0.0.1:52840.
BAM
NCAT DEBUG: Closing connection.
```

#### Terminal B

```
>echo BAM | ncat -4vv 127.0.0.1 5001
Ncat: Version 7.12 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using trusted CA certificates from ...
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:5001 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.0.1:5001]
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:5001.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.0.1:5001] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 26 [peer unspecified] (6 bytes): BAM ..
libnsock nsock_write(): Write request for 6 bytes to IOD #1 EID 35 [127.0.0.1:5001]
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 35 [127.0.0.1:5001]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 42
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 42 [peer unspecified]
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 18 [(null):-1]
close: Result too large
```

The first time I run ncat in Terminal B, it hangs for about 1s at `TCP connection requested to 127.0.0.1:5001`. The sockets hang in states SYN_SENT and SYN_RCVD ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTWtw.png)).

On subsequent runs (ncat -k in Terminal A keeps listening), the connection builds up immediately, which is what I expect and also see on other Windows 7 and Linux systems.

I feel that this delay in creating TCP connections is slowing down software (e.g. an IPython console connecting to a kernel on the same machine).

*What's going on?*

Additional info:

- Windows Firewall is off.
- Deactivating all network adapters in control
  panel doesn't help.
- I see this e.g. in my Python programs when using
  sockets; I am using ncat as the most basic test.

Comment: Do you see this issue when connecting to the server externally, i.e. not using a localhost connection? How does SSH/FTP/HTTP etc behave?

Comment: Yes, I do. Same symptoms as in the localhost case, i.e. creating the first connection takes ~1s and further connections are instantaneous. I have not checked higher level protocols.

Comment: Can you take a packet capture with Wireshark when you run the tests and email me the capture file: markopolo.stackexchange@gmail.com?